# Finding out the potential

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, potential

[image]

> According to me, if we want to find out the potential the the equation
>   will be, $$dV = \int \frac{dQ}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 x}$$.

But the answer is given is on the basis of
$$dV = \int \frac{dQ}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 \sqrt{(R^2+ x^2)}}$$.

> Why the the distance x from the center of the radious is not allowed to get the potential?

Comment: I think you should think about what the meaning of the 'distance' in the denominator is.

Comment: There once was a guy named Pythagoras...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you consider a small element having a very small charge, you assume it to be placed on the ring. The distance of all such points from the point where you want to find the potential is constant and hence the answer can be simply calculated to be (B)

Your assunption that potential should depend on the distance from center is correct, but it is more appropriately incorporated when we consider the distance from the suppsed small elements which lie on the rings body and not its center and hence the distance is invloved not as x but as (R2+x2)^(1/2)

Answer (score 1):

The measure of length that is present in the equation for the potential is supposed to measure the distance between the *source* of the potential and the point at which you evaluate the potential. Now, in this question the source is clearly the ring of charge, and the point P where you evaluate the potential is on the $y=0$ line at position $x$. This means that the total distance between the source and the point P is...